# falid to start gnome display manager

Tags: ubuntu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W2Mm.jpg)

Hello everyone
I have a computer with the Ubuntu operating system, and I encountered the following error when I turned it on. and Unfortunately, I did not find a way to type the command when it started

and ctrl+shift+f# ( # = 1 to 9 ) not working to type the script

Comment: have a look inside `systemctl status gdm.service` and post on https://askubuntu.com/